# Nodemon ignore folder using regex expressions

Tags: regex, node.js, nodemon

In Nodemon ignore file I want to selectively ignore the folders from my main folder.

My folder structure is :

```
-modules
  -accounts
 -client
     -angularfiles
        -accounts.js
 -repository
      -accountrepository.js    
-bankbranch
 -client
     -angularfiles
         -bankbranch.js
 -repository
      -bankbranchrepository.js
```

In this hierarchy I want to ignore file paths "modules/accounts/client/angularfiles/" &
"modules/bankbranch/client/angularfiles/"

I have many more such modules. In this case I tried writing this regex to ignore based on the expression like so :

```
/modules\\\w*\\client\\angularfiles\\*/
```

Using the online regex matcher it matches this path :

```
\AngularJSApp\modules\accounts\client\angularfiles\bankbranch.js
```

but nodemon restarts when the file in client\angularfiles is changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nodemon relies on file patterns rather than regular expressions for ignoring some files.

Try this instead:

```
nodemon --ignore 'modules/**/client/angularfiles/*'
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. It worked!!  Added the same in .nodemonignore file.